# Tensorflow: Replace indices in 3D tensor using 2D tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

- I have a 3D tensor `X`, of shape `[7, 240, 768]`.
- I have another tensor `mask_idx` of shape `[7, 240]` which contains
  `0/False` and `1/True`, where `0/False` means I don't want to
  update the value in `X[i][j]` and `1/True` means I want to do
  this `X[i][j] = tf.zeros([768])`.

I have tried using `tf.where(mask_idx, tf.zeros([7, 240, 768]), X)` but getting this error:

> *** tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: condition [7,240], then [7,240,768], and else [7,240,768] must be broadcastable [Op:SelectV2]

Can anyone suggest the correct approach to it?

Comment: translate the tensor to have the 768 as first dimension, then it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TF checks if dimensions are broadcastable from *right to left*, so one simple way is to expand your mask tensor in the last dimension, i.e., make its shape `(7,240,1)`.

```
tf.where(mask_idx[...,None], 0, X)
```